# JPA select query

Tags: java, sql, jpa, jpql, discriminator

I am creating this subject after 2h of research in vain.

I am trying to do a very simple car location code which could save, remove get data from database.

So my problem is I have a parent class named Vehicule and 2 children class : car and van.
Below, there are the beginning of my 3 classes

```
// vehicule
@Entity
@Table(name="Vehicule")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="vehicule_type")
@Inheritance
public class Vehicule implements Serializable{
// some constructors setters and getters here
}

// car
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Car")
public class Car extends Vehicule{  
    @Column(name = "number_of_seats")
    private int nbOfSeats;
    // some constructors setters and getters here
}

// van
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("Van")
public class Van extends Vehicule{
    @Column(name = "max_weight")
    private int maxWeight;
    // some constructors setters and getters here
}
```

I stored them in a single table with inheritanceStratregy = single table.
Now, i would like to select only cars or only vans.

I tried

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM Vehicule v WHERE v.vehicule_type = 'Car'");
List<Car> list = (List<Car>) query.getResultList();
```

but i got

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager:
The state field path 'v.vehicule_type' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

I also tried

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Car> q = cb.createQuery(Car.class);
Root<Car> c = q.from(Car.class);
ParameterExpression<String> p = cb.parameter(String.class);

q.select(c).where(cb.equal(c.get("vehicule_type"), p));

TypedQuery<Car> query = em.createQuery(q);
query.setParameter(p, "Car");
List<Car> results = query.getResultList();
```

but i got

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [vehicule_type] is not present in the managed type
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: you do not need to append vehicule_type in your criteria. JPA appends it by itself because you say select from Vehicule... try SELECT v FROM Vehicule v

Comment: i meened "SELECT v FROM Car v" ... "SELECT v FROM Vehicule v" does only work, if you give your Vehicule class a DiscriminatorValue, too.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the complete fields of your "Vehicule" entity.
But if you have on your Vehicule table, a field name "vehicule_type"
You ust have to specify it in your code with name "vehiculeType"

Just try to change "vehicule_type" to "vehiculeType"

But for more help, I think that you must provide the content of your Vehicle entity class.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Is there any field with the name vehicule_type? I doubt that it is not present and somehow you are trying to access it which is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

You never need to insert where criterias for discriminator values. JPA do this itself. You just have to select the right entity.

In your case you should just select: "SELECT v FROM Car v".
If you turn on show_sql in your configuration, you will see that JPA adds where aliasXX.vehicule_type = 'Car' automatically